# Python How to make array in array?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, types

I have a numpy array Z1, Z2, Z3:
    `Z1 = [1,2,3]`
    `Z2 = [4,5]`
    `Z3 = [6,7,8,9]`
I want new numpy array Z that have Z1, Z2, Z3 as array like:
    `Z = [[1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7,8,9]`
    `print(type(Z),type(Z[0]))`
    `>>> <class 'numpy.ndarray'> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>`
I used np.append, hstack, vstack, insert, concatenate ...but all I failed.
There is only 2 case:
    `Z = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`
or ERROR
so I made a list Z first, and append list Z1, Z2, Z3 and then convert list Z into numpy array Z.
BUT
    `Z = [[1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7,8,9]]`
    `print(type(Z),type(Z[0]))`
    `>>> <class 'numpy.ndarray'> <class 'list'>`

I want to do not use 'while' or 'for'. Help me please..

Comment: This should work I guess `z = np.array([Z1, Z2, Z3])`

Comment: Your arrays aren't all the same length. What do you expect the shape of the final array to be?

Comment: Since your arrays are of different lengths each, it's impossible to create an an ndarray using them

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
import numpy as np

Z1 = [1,2,3]
Z2 = [4,5]
Z3 = [6,7,8,9]

Z = np.array([Z1, Z2, Z3])
print(Z)
print(type(Z))
```

This will convert your list of lists into an numpy array

Comment: That's just an array of Python objects though: note that `type(Z[0])` returns `<class 'list'>`. So you might as well just use a plain Python list of lists. Numpy's fast array manipulations only work on arrays whose base items are native data types, not Python objects.

Answer (score 1):

First, `Z` is a list of lists:

```
In [33]: Z = [[1,2,3], [4,5], [6,7,8,9]]
```

This is an array of lists - note the dtype.  But keep in mind that `np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])` will produce a 2d array of dtype int.

```
In [34]: np.array(Z)
Out[34]: array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]], dtype=object)
```

The surest way of creating an array of object dtype, and given shape is to initialize it, and then fill it:

```
In [35]: out = np.zeros((3,), dtype=object)
In [36]: out[...] = Z
In [37]: out
Out[37]: array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]], dtype=object)
```

Again this is an array of lists.  To make an array of arrays, we first have to make a list of arrays:

```
In [38]: out[...] = [np.array(x) for x in Z]
In [39]: out
Out[39]: array([array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5]), array([6, 7, 8, 9])], dtype=object)
```

Object arrays are awkward beasts, not quite lists and not quite (regular) arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make that array. Arrays is numpy are similar to matrices in math. They have to be *m*rows, each having *n* columns. Use a list of lists, or list of `np.array`s

Answer (score 0):

everybody thanks! Answers are a little bit different with that I want, but eventually I solve that without use 'for' or 'while'.

First, I made "numpy array" Z1, Z2, Z3 and put them into "list" Z. There are array in List.

Second, I convert "list" Z into "numpy array" Z. It is array in array that I want.